# Not understood behavior of Numpy genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading a .csv file with numpy and it is resulting in some weird behavior. I was using the same commands with python27 and now this is happening with python34.

This is the file I am reading

```
Time,Extension,Load,Tensile strain (Extension) (s),(mm),(N),(%)
"0.00000","0.00000","0.13123","0.00000"
"0.10000","-0.28935","0.10751","-0.18986"
"0.20000","-0.60456","0.05810","-0.39669"
"0.30000","-0.90619","0.02766","-0.59462"
"0.40000","-1.20641","0.02427","-0.79161"
"0.50000","-1.50580","0.01883","-0.98806"
```

As you can see it has quotes around the values, I was used to getting rid of that by using `np.char.rstrip(rawData, '"')`, but that is no longer working.

My main problem is that when I read the file using the following

```
rawData = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',', dtype=None
```

the resulting components of the array look like this

```
[[b'Time' b'Extension' b'Load' b'Tensile strain (Extension)']
[b'(s)' b'(mm)' b'(N)' b'(%)']
 [b'"0.00000"' b'"0.00000"' b'"0.31663"' b'"0.00000"']
 ..., 
 [b'"55.40200"' b'"0.45994"' b'"-0.03573"' b'"0.30180"']
 [b'"55.50200"' b'"0.15926"' b'"-0.05247"' b'"0.10450"']
 [b'"55.55600"' b'"-0.00283"' b'"-0.04758"' b'"-0.00186"']
```

where is that *b* coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3 uses unicode as its default string type.  The file has ASCII (byte length) strings.  `genfromtxt` is reading them without converting to unicode, so they are displayed in Python3's bytestring format.

Your `"` edit should work if you remove `b'"'` rather than the unicode version:

```
np.char.rstrip(rawData, b'"')
```

Look at the code for `genfromtxt`.  The first thing it does is convert your regular (unicode in Python3) strings and chars to bytes:

```
# Py3 data conversions to bytes, for convenience
if comments is not None:
    comments = asbytes(comments)
if isinstance(delimiter, unicode):
    delimiter = asbytes(delimiter)
if isinstance(missing, unicode):
    missing = asbytes(missing)
if isinstance(missing_values, (unicode, list, tuple)):
    missing_values = asbytes_nested(missing_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the numpy reader to give a string instead of bytes.

Using the following to read the file allowed my original code written for python24 work without a problem.

```
tempData = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(path,file),delimiter=',',dtype=None).astype(str)
```